# First price auctions in economics

Tags: game-theory

Suppose a single unit of a good is to be sold at an auction. There are two bidders who
may have different valuations of the object to be sold. The set of types T
i = {vH, vL},
where i = 1, 2. The vL-type has a low valuation of the good whereas the vH-type has a high
valuation. The probabilities of being a high or a low type are common knowledge. The seller
wants to maximise expected revenue.
Now suppose the probability that any player is of the vH-type is 0.7, and the probability
that any player is of the vL-type is 0.3. In a second-price auction, calculate the
probability that each type of player wins, their expected payment and their expected surplus.

The answer given is: In a second-price auction, truthful bidding is a dominant strategy for each type of player.
The probabilities of winning for each type of player is:
ρ(vH)=13/20 and ρ(vL)=3/20.
How did they calculate ρ(vH)?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a vH type.  She has a 0.7 chance of facing another vH type, in which case, since they both truthfully reveal their valuation, our vH person has a 0.5 chance of winning--that is, if they have a tie bid, they flip a coin or some such way to decide.  So 0.7 time 0.5 is 0.35 chance.  There is a 0.3 chance that the vH type faces an vL type, and then the vH type wins with certainty.  So total chance of winning is 0.65, which is 13/20.

vL type: 0.7 chance of losing for sure, and 0.3 times 0.5 chance of winning (by facing another vL type) or  0.15, or 15/100, or 3/20.

Of course, this answer is formally incomplete because I did not prove truthful bidding is a dominant strategy.